# How to Specify an Exact Fire Time for an Android Notification?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I'm trying to schedule notifications at an exact time on Android devices using Unity's mobile notifications package. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to set the exact time (down to the second) to schedule the notification.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void SetupAndroidNotifications()
{
  var time = DateTime.Now;

  for (var i = 0; i < eventBehavior.events.Length; i++)
  {
    // Skip events that have already passed
    if (i + 1 < time.DayOfYear)
      continue;

    var notification = new AndroidNotification
    {
      Title = $"Day {i + 1}",
      Text = "Today's event will occure in one minute",
      // HERE IS WHERE THE TIME TO FIRE THE NOTIFICATION IS SCHEDULED
      FireTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays((i + 1) - DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
    };

    var identifier = AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "REDACTED");

    // Prevent duplicate notifications
    if (AndroidNotificationCenter.CheckScheduledNotificationStatus(identifier) != NotificationStatus.Scheduled) 
      continue;
            
    AndroidNotificationCenter.CancelNotification(identifier);
    AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "REDACTED");
  }
}
```

This method schedules a notification for every single event inside a list. There is one event per day. Each event occurs at a different time.

**The issue is that DateTime doesn't allow you to construct a very specific time.**

Any ideas on how I could specify an exact time using DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime constructor allows you to specify a specific time.

```
private void SetupAndroidNotifications()
{
  var time = DateTime.Now;

  for (var i = 0; i < eventBehavior.events.Length; i++)
  {
    // Skip events that have already passed
    if (i + 1 < time.DayOfYear)
      continue;

    var thisEvent = eventBehavior.events[i];
    var monthDay = DateTime.FromOADate(i + 2);
    var notification = new AndroidNotification
    {
      Title = $"Day {i + 1}",
      Text = "Today's event will occuring in one minute",
      // FIXED HERE. USING DATETIME CONSTRUCTOR TO SPECIFY TIME
      FireTime = new DateTime(2022, monthDay.Month, monthDay.Day, thisEvent.hour, thisEvent.minute, 0)
    };

    var identifier = AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "REDACTED");

    // Prevent duplicate notifications
    if (AndroidNotificationCenter.CheckScheduledNotificationStatus(identifier) != NotificationStatus.Scheduled) 
      continue;
            
    AndroidNotificationCenter.CancelNotification(identifier);
    AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "REDACTED");
  }
}
```